# RTP livestream to browser using FFMPEG/nginx

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, live-streaming

I have a streaming transcoder which converts a high bandwidth fiber stream to a multicast RTP stream. I want to be able to show this stream to a client in a browser. There are 2 issues if I understand correctly:

1. The client most likely does not support multicast over his network
2. RTP cannot be played in a browser, so this needs to be converted to another format

What I have done so far (using FFMPEG):

Method 1: copy the stream to a .m3u8 without muxing, then hosting it with a Webserver (Nginx)
`ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp -i ./stream.sdp -c:v copy -c:a copy -bufsize 50k -flags -global_header -hls_time 1 -f hls -hls_playlist_type event -hls_list_size 3 ./video/stream.m3u8`

Method 2: enable HLS on Nginx and convert the stream to RTMP
`ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp -i ./stream.sdp -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -acodec aac -strict -2 -f flv rtmp://localhost/show/stream`

Both of these methods result in a working livestream, but the delay remains around 5 seconds.

Is there any way to make the livestream faster? The multicast livestream has around a 1 second delay at max.

Answer (score 0):

`Both of these methods result in a working livestream, but the delay remains around 5 seconds.`

Thats actually really good for HLS. Yes, there are ways to be faster within things Luke WebRTC and CTE. But nothing standard, You would have to develop the player and a chunk of infrastructure yourself.